# Expand and hence find (Series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

After trying some more questions on Series I'm coming across problems that are rather similar but can't quite grasp what the question is asking for.

---

The question is as follows:

> Write the first four terms of the series expansion of $e^x$ and hence find $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(r+1)!3^r}$$

---

The series expansion of $e^x$ is:
$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{!2} + \frac{x^3}{!3} + \frac{x^4}{!4}$$

However I can't seem seem to integrate that with the question in any way and am kindly asking for help.

---

Comment: `\infty` Hint: Start from the expansion of $\exp(1/3)$.

Comment: I would then expand with $e^{1/3}$ and compare the results? Also thanks for the `\infty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that our expression is equal to 
$$3\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{(r+1)!3^{r+1}},$$
and
$$\sum_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{(r+1)!3^{r+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}-1-\frac{x}{1!},$$
where $x=1/3$.

Comment: I'm really trying to wrap my head around it but can't quite seem to. May I ask for a more elaborate answer?

Comment: Let $y$ be our sum. Then by the two displayed formulas, $\frac{y}{3}=e^{1/3}-1-\frac{1}{3}$. Now we can solve for $y$.

Comment: Ah alright, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Our sum is a close relative of the sum $\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for $x=1/3$, that is, of $e^{1/3}.